# Javascript - change table according to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched for the question and found similar stuff but nothing that I can relate too.

I'm on an internship and I'm working on a platform using Javascript.

I have a set of values and I need the user to enter an input. Then I need to fill a table according to this input (i.e. only keep the lines where value <= input)

The catch is, I don't want the page to reload. When the user enters his input, I want the table to change without refreshing the page.

I'm really struggling with this one, can anybody help me?

From what I understand, I would need a first Javascript function to read the input. Then a second one to browse my values and to fill a list with the ones that fit the input. And finally, a third one to display a row of the table for each of this value.

Here's an example : my form

```
   <form id="bottomForm">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="asking_dist">Distance range (Kb)</label>
            <input id="asking_dist" type="text" size="5" name="asking_dist"/>
        </fieldset>

    </form>
```

I would need a first Javascript function to get that input, etc.

How can I proceed?

Comment: setup a jsfiddle (google it) to help us understand what you are doing, also provide information on which javascript frameworks you are using (jQuery?)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function someStuff()
{
 var value = document.getElementById('asking_dist').value; //Textbox value
  var html = '<tr><td>'+value+'</td><tr>'
  $('#tdata').append(html);
  document.getElementById('asking_dist').value = '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="bottomForm">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="asking_dist">Distance range (Kb)</label>
    <input id="asking_dist" type="text" size="5" name="asking_dist"/>
    <input type="button" value="Append" onClick="someStuff(this.value);">
  </fieldset>
</form>
<table id="tdata" border = "2">
  <tr><th>Value</th></tr>
</table>
```

Try this
This will help you
Happy Coding......